# How to define customized command in cmd prompt for directory navigation?

Tags: cmd, command, command-prompt

Say I want to navigate to a directory but don't want typing the directory every time.

Is there a way to define a customized short keys in the cmd prompt like

`set root=C:\Users\sz\to\this\path`

So next time only typing `cd root` can direct me to the target root. I hope the short key will be stored permanently - when I re-open the cmd prompt, the short key is still valid.

Even better, is it possible to define a short key that only typing `root` (without typing `cd`) can do the same thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cd %root%` would work after your `set`command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doskey root=cd /d "C:\Users\sz\to\this\path"
```

Note: the macro is gone, if you close your cmd-window

**EDIT**

another way is a batchfile somewhere in the path, for example `root.bat` as a "one-liner":

```
@cd /d "C:\Users\sz\to\this\path"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - works like magic! But is there a way to store the macro somewhere for usage? That would be even more handy.

Comment: sure there is. It can be stored in the registry somehow - but I'm not a specialist in that. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/2152082