# Open command shell and execute command

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to open a new shell and pass a command for it to execute in a single line of code from the windows cmd window.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

For example I have a cmd shell and I want to execute:

```
C:\app\cmd.exe THEN "run_app.exe argument1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a command on command prompt startup in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows)

Comment: it's a specific cmd prompt, not just the standard one,

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd /c run_app.exe argument
```

to **c**lose after executing or

```
cmd /k run_app.exe argument
```

to **k**eep open after executing.

If in doubt, use full paths to your executable:

```
cmd /c c:\path\to\run_app.exe argument
```

To run several commands one after another, use chaining:

```
   cmd /k run_app.exe argument & second.exe & third.exe
```

Comment: so the issue I'm getting is that i run the first command "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /k cd C:\Program Files\myapp" then I want to run "execute_app.exe arg1" afterwards but when I add the -k it says  "the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: Why `cd` there and not directly run `cmd /k c:\path\to\run_app.exe`?

Comment: Lots of applications require a particular current directory, often but not necessarily the one the executable lives in.  The simplest approach is usually to set the current directory before calling `cmd /c` and let the child shell inherit it.