# How can I return to the previous directory in windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line, cmd, doskey

I often want to return to the previous directory I was just in in cmd.exe, but windows does not have the "cd -" functionality of Unix.  Also typing cd ../../.. is a lot of typing.

Is there a faster way to go up several directory levels?

And ideally return back afterwards?

Comment: just type on the cmd cd ../

Comment: No that just moves up a directory, not latterly for example.  Or to a different drive letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run cmd.exe using the /k switch and a starting batch file that invokes doskey to use an enhanced versions of the cd command.

Here is a simple batch file to change directories to the first parameter (%1) passed in, and to remember the initial directory by calling pushd %1.

### md_autoruns.cmd:

```
@echo off
cd %1
pushd %1
title aliases active
cls
%SystemRoot%\System32\doskey.exe /macrofile=c:\tools\aliases
```

---

We will also need a small helper batch file to remember the directory changes and to ignore changes to the same directory:

### mycd.bat:

```
@echo off
if '%*'=='' cd & exit /b
if '%*'=='-' (
    cd /d %OLDPWD%
    set OLDPWD="%cd%"
) else (
    cd /d %*
    if not errorlevel 1 set OLDPWD="%cd%"
)
```

---

And a small aliases file showing what to do to make it all work:

### aliases:

```
cd=C:\tools\mycd.bat $*
cd\=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..
A:=c:\tools\mycd.bat A:
B:=c:\tools\mycd.bat B:
C:=c:\tools\mycd.bat C:
...
Z:=c:\tools\mycd.bat Z:
.=cd
..=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..
...=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..
....=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..
.....=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..\..
......=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..\..\..
.......=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..\..\..\..
........=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..\..\..\..\..
.........=c:\tools\mycd.bat ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..
tools=c:\tools\mycd.bat C:\tools
wk=c:\tools\mycd.bat %WORKSPACE%
```

---

Now you can go up a directory level by typing `..`

Add another `.` for each level you want to go up.

When you want to go back, type `cd -` and you will be back where you started.

Aliases to jump to directories like `wk` or `tools` (shown above) swiftly take you from location to location, are easy to create, and can really help if you work in the command line frequently.

Comment: This is great. Also, if you want this to work in all of your command prompts just follow the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows

Answer (score 21):

**Steps:**

1. `pushd .`  (Keep old folder path on the stack)
2. `cd ..\..` (Move to the folder whare you like to)
3. `popd`          (Pop it from the stack. Meaning, Come back to the old folder)

Comment: This works but.. seems only convenient in a script, not regular usage.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in **powershell**

```
cd ..
```

Comment: This command moves to the parent directory. The OP is asking for a way to move to the *previous* directory, regardless of its location in the hierarchy.

Comment: I don't know why users take down votes to my answer, it is one of solutions for return to previous  directory, what is wrong here?

Comment: Read my comment for the answer...

Comment: @Malcolm Your answer is not correct, I just noticed that this working for me in powershell.

Comment: `cd C:\Windows`, `cd C:\Users`, `cd ..` leaves you at `C:` - OP is asking for a command that would take you back to `C:\Windows`

Answer (score 9):

On Windows CMD, I got used to using `pushd` and `popd`. Before changing directory I use `pushd .` to put the current directory on the stack, and then I use cd to move elsewhere. You can run pushd as often as you like, each time the specified directory goes on the stack. You can then CD to whatever directory, or directories , that you want. It does not matter how many times you run CD.  When ready to return , I use `popd`  to return to whatever directory is on top of the stack.   This is suitable for simple use cases and is handy, as long as you remember to push a directory on the stack before using CD.

Comment: I was hoping for something built in, that didn't depend on me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by a hybrid doskey/batch-file implementation.
It replaces the built-in CD command with a DOSKEY macro.

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:function:\..\MyBatchFile.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L


doskey cd=for %%# in ( 1 1 2) do @if %%#==2 ( "%~d0\:__cd:\..\%~pnx0" ) else set args=$*

exit /b

:__cd

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (""!args!"") DO (
  endlocal
  if "%%~a"=="" (
      if /i not "%CD%"=="%USERPROFILE%" (
          chdir /d "%USERPROFILE%" && set "OLDPWD=%CD%"
      ) 
  ) else if "%%~a"=="-" (
       if /i not "%CD%"=="%OLDPWD%" (
            chdir /d "%OLDPWD%" && set "OLDPWD=%CD%"
       ) 
  ) else (
        if /i not "%CD%"=="%%~a" (
            chdir /d %%~a && set "OLDPWD=%CD%"
        )
  )
)
```

Now it's possible to use

```
C:\> cd C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\System32> cd C:\users
C:\Users> cd -
C:\Windows\System32> cd -
C:\Users>
```

The source and more information at [Sanitizing command parameters in a DOSKEY macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76212759/463115)

Answer (score -3):

**You could use the command:**

```
cd ..\       -> To go up one level
cd ..\..\    -> To go up two levels
```

Note the space after `cd`

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score -3):

`cd ..` works for me in ubuntu.

Check second most voted answer.

[image]