# How do you automatically run commands for interactive shells?

Tags: windows, shell

I am looking for the [rc file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/rc-file.html). I want to execute

```
chcp 65001 > nul
cd %TEMP%
```

each time a new interactive shell is started. System info:

```
Clink v0.4.8 [git:d565ad] Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Martin Ridgers
http://mridgers.github.io/clink

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]

myuser@MYHOST C:\Users\myuser
$ choco info conemu | rg -i ^^conemu
ConEmu 18.4.29.0 [Approved] Downloads cached for licensed users

myuser@MYHOST C:\Users\myuser
$ █
```

Comment: @TarunLalwani Judging from the system info, it looks like it might be [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: This system is using clink and so it must be using CMD.  Arguably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Clink, it adds itself to the shell's autorun registry entry. The way it does this is by [registering the `.bat` file used to run it](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/e379ecda2c6abaed66aa97614e37e24f0f4d0945/clink/app/src/loader/autorun.cpp#L281). This way, every time you start a new shell, this file is run. Therefore all you have to do is open `clink.bat` and add your commands to the launch section at the end of the file, before clink is spawned:

```
:launch
chcp 65001 > nul
cd %TEMP%
start /b "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
exit /b 0
```

(Notice I use `start /b` so it preserves your new code page)