# Can Intellij automatically run commands when opening the embedded terminal?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I use the embedded terminal intellij on Windows and I always run a set of commands as soon as it opens. Commands such as setting aliases etc etc. Is it possible to get intellij to run the automatically?

Comment: Rather not but you can create .bat file to run all commands. So you will run only one command. There are enviroment variables in terminal section in settings, look there first.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not currently supported; please follow [IDEA-210036](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210036) for updates.

Note that you can set up init script in the AutoRun registry value to execute a set of commands on each *cmd.exe* start - see
[How to run a command on command prompt startup in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows). But this will affect all your cmd shell instances, not just the *cmd.exe* in the terminal embedded in WebStorm