# need to activate myenv every time I use python in order to use packages

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables

I had an issue with my anaconda and I had to reinstalled it. I set the path to my environment variable and installed everything correctly but every time I open cmd and type 'python' I get a warning to activate my environment.

I can still use base python despite the warning but I cant import any packages at all, if I try I get the module not found error.

So I type the command "activate " and then I can enter python and I can use all my packages just fine. The problem is that I have to type "activate " every time I open a new cmd or the old issue keeps appearing.

Also when I write any code in my sublime text editor I cannot use any packages at all, just the base python. It seems my environment is not getting activated unless I type in the command, but then it goes away each cmd session and I cant use sublime text with any packages.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?  I have spent most of the day trying to get this to work

Comment: What system are you on? Windows cmd?  Linux bash? Is Powershell an option?

Comment: oops I am using windows 10

Comment: That's how virtual environments work, they're not supposed to replace your local python, that's the whole point

Comment: Well it's pretty easy if you use Powershell rather than cmd.  You can edit the $profile variable and put in the line ```conda activate myenv``` .  https://superuser.com/a/886960  Otherwise if you use cmd you have to mess about with registry keys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows

Comment: @Sayse true enough but if you mostly work in one virtual env its convenient to activate it every time you open a new window, then just deactivate it as needed.

Comment: I just dont get why I cant use any packages with sublime even though everything is set up. I never had to activate my environment every time before

Comment: Don't manipulate `PATH`, but instead use `conda init` to configure your shell. Duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918) has the latest best practice.