# How to make the resolution of the user path having priority over the system path?

Tags: windows, path-variables

In windows system, the order of the different paths in `PATH` variable environnement defines the resolution priority :

Example:

- If the path is constituted of the following : `C:/Dir1;C/Dir2`
- And containing `C:/Dir1/test.exe` and `C:/Dir2/test.exe`
- Running `test.exe` in cmd will resolve into `C:/Dir1/test.exe`

That's fine, but in Windows there is two PATH, the user one and the system one. And there are concatenated as following : `<system-path>;<user-path>`

So, the system path seems to always have priority over the user path.

Am I wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I trying to only modify the user path (so without admin privilege) (let's say adding `C:/Dir2`), but if the system path contains a path that's already resolve `test.exe` (let's say `C:/Dir1`), so the `C:/Dir2` will not resolve `test.exe`.  (Assuming `test.exe` is in both `C:/Dir1` and `C:/Dir2`)

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using PowerShell

The function `GetEnvironmentVariable` can get user's and system's variables separately. So you can add following settings to your `$PROFILE`, which is usually `$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`:

```bash
$env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User") + ';' + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
```

Or if you want to prepend some paths to current `$env:PATH`, instead of moving whole user's paths before system's, you can just add:

```bash
$env:PATH = 'C:\Dir1;' + $env:PATH # note there's a semicolon
```

### For Command Prompt

Refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1240846):

> If you only need this to work for command prompt sessions, create a profile/init batch file and configure it in the registry, per [How to run a command on command prompt startup in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows). E.g.,
>
> ```
> reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun ^
>  /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%\init.cmd" /f
> ```
>
> Then simply make modifications to the PATH in that batch file. E.g.,
>
> ```
> SET USER_PATH=c:\whatever
> SET PATH=%USER_PATH%;%PATH%
> ```