# I want to run a python script or an executable everytime i open command prompt either through Run or search or using the toolbar in the Explorer

Tags: python, cmd

Can I run a script or a .exe file every time the command prompt is executed from various methods?
like maybe through Run or the toolbar in Explorer or anywhere.
I want to run a script and show something in the command prompt as an output.

Comment: Clarify "everytime commandprompt is executed". Do you mean every time the cmd console is launched?

Comment: yes everytime you launch the cmd.

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows>

Comment: Please do __not__ use registry value `AutoRun` of registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`. That would be really a very bad idea. The command line specified here is executed whenever `cmd.exe` is executed independent on which process started `cmd.exe`. `cmd.exe` starts itself for example on usage of `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B 2^>nul') do echo File "%%I"` in a batch file. Thousands of programs and scripts run in background `cmd.exe` indirectly (most often without programmer knowing that). So usage of `AutoRun` would be a very bad idea in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to run Python script/code on cmd then run this code:
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(filename.py,output_name.pyc)

This will create a .pyc file which you can then run in cmd using command:
python output_name.pyc

note: filename and output_name are both strings that should include fileextensions and you can write any name here.